# What could the reason for Neatbeans saying 'No library found for namespace http://primefaces.org.ui' even when i have add the primefaces 5.0 library?

Tags: netbeans, primefaces

My project is not Maven (it's JavaEE application). I have tried adding different versions of PrimeFaces, not at the same time, but I'm still facing this problem. Actually it works fine when I run the project. Below is the namespace:

```
xmlns:p =''http://primefaces.org.ui''
```

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly have a space in the namespace and you are also using single quotes instead of quotation marks:

```
xmlns:p =''http://primefaces.org.ui''
```

Change it to:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

For more help on setting up primefaces, take a look at their guide [here.](http://primefaces.org/gettingstarted)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've tried it as you told me, but the error is still appearing. One thing i noticed is that the project does not show any error when i try on another Netbeans (i.e 11.2) version on my computer.

Comment: Please can you provide more details? Hard to know what's going wrong without seeing your code and configuration.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the question.